# How do I apply an EtchedBorder to only a specific side of the border?

Tags: java, swing, border

I have a JPanel where I want to add an EtchedBorder.Lowered to only the left border. I know this is possible with MatteBorders, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this with an EtchedBorder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- use [JSeparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/separator.html) instead of EtchedBorder.Lowered,
- but JSeparator is by default only line, but you are able to build funny Borders

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class NestedLayout {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();

    public NestedLayout() {
        leftPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        leftPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                10, //top
                10, //left
                10, //bottom
                10));   //right
        leftPanel.add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.VERTICAL), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        leftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NestedLayout();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a JSeparator using FlowLayout? This is what I currently have with a FlowLayout implementation using JSeparator to separate JLabels for a status bar. http://pastebin.com/J79DsqMJ

Answer (score 4):

You can join two panels and add an 'opposite' matted border on each to recreate the etched effect :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    public MainFrame() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel left = new JPanel();
        left.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));
        left.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 1, Color.GRAY));
        add(left, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JPanel center = new JPanel();
        center.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));
        center.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 0, 0, Color.WHITE));
        add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If the JSeparator doesn't work with panel with FlowLayout, then I might just use this.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create your own border class by sub-classing EtchedBorder or AbstractBorder.

This code will do exactly what you asked: an EtchedBorder drawn on one side only.  But it doesn't look good.  An EtchedBorder simply draws two lines (one dark, one light) on each side.  It gets its 3-dimensional look from the way the lines meet at the corners.  Without the full box drawn, it doesn't look 3-dimensional.

```
setBorder(new EtchedBorder() {
  public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    g.setColor(getShadowColor(c));
    g.drawLine(x, y + height - 2, x, y);

    g.setColor(getHighlightColor(c));
    g.drawLine(x+1, y + height - 3, x+1, y + 1);
  }
});
```

Comment: May want to wrap with `g.translate(x,y) ... g.translate(-x,-y)`.  See the current implementation in EtchedBorder.

Answer (score 2):

Extending on the answer given by Yanflea where you create an 'opposite' from two different panels to replicate the look of an etched border.

You can create it on one panel using a `CompoundBorder` like so:

```
 CompoundBorder border = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
          BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.WHITE),
          BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.GRAY)
          ); // This would create A line on the bottom
```

The advantage of doing this way is that you can also do two sides which then looks like this: (Note that this is just a grid of nine panels and only the middle has the border, which also a thicker than 1 *See the code below, I used setBackground on panels to show where each panel was*)

[image]!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        JFrame f = new JFrame("A Demo");
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        f.setSize(400,400);
        JPanel j1 = new JPanel();       //j1.setBackground(new Color(255,0,0));
        JPanel j2 = new JPanel();       //j2.setBackground(new Color(200,0,0));
        JPanel j3 = new JPanel();       //j3.setBackground(new Color(150,0,0));
        JPanel j4 = new JPanel();       //j4.setBackground(new Color(100,0,0));
        JPanel j5 = new JPanel();       //j5.setBackground(new Color(0,255,0));
        JPanel j6 = new JPanel();       //j6.setBackground(new Color(0,200,0));
        JPanel j7 = new JPanel();       //j7.setBackground(new Color(50,0,0));
        JPanel j8 = new JPanel();       //j8.setBackground(new Color(0,150,0));
        JPanel j9 = new JPanel();       //j9.setBackground(new Color(0,100,0));
        j5.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
              BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 2, Color.WHITE),
              BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 2, Color.GRAY)
              ));   
        f.add(j1);
        f.add(j2);
        f.add(j3);
        f.add(j4);
        f.add(j5);
        f.add(j6);
        f.add(j7);
        f.add(j8);
        f.add(j9);  
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```